# html dynamic table values

Tags: javascript, html

im new to coding and try to build a dynamic table.
1st column works fine every new cell goes to top . want to do the same on second 3rd etc.. but when i try to add column to table fills from top to bottom.
i want my table to look like

```
5|5|5
4|4|4
3|3|3
2|2|2
1|1|1
0|0|0
```

```js
function createcolumn() {
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++){
  var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  var row = table.insertRow(0);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  cell1.innerHTML = "NEW CELL1 - "+i;
 
}
}

function createCell(cell, text, style) {
    var div = document.createElement('div'), // create DIV element
        txt = document.createTextNode(text); // create text node
    div.appendChild(txt);                    // append text node to the DIV
    div.setAttribute('class', style);        // set DIV class attribute
    div.setAttribute('className', style);    // set DIV class attribute for IE (?!)
    cell.appendChild(div);                   // append DIV to the table cell
}

function addcolumn() {
    var tbl = document.getElementById('myTable'), // table reference
        i;
    // open loop for each row and append cell
    //for (i = 0; i < tbl.rows.length; i++) {
    for (i = 5; i < tbl.rows.length; i--) {
        createCell(tbl.rows[i].insertCell(tbl.rows[i].cells.length), i, 'col');
    }
}
```

```css
table, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to add a new row at the first position of the table and then add cells and content.</p>

<table id="myTable">

</table>
<br>

<button type="button" onclick="createcolumn()">1st column</button>
<button type="button" onclick="addcolumn()">add column</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: I tried your snippet, get error:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'insertCell')

Answer (score 0):

With your add column function, you can do 5-i instead of just i, that'll display what you want.

```
createCell(tbl.rows[i].insertCell(tbl.rows[i].cells.length), 5-i, 'col');
```